# custom secure jsf tag implementation

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, myfaces, custom-tags

I want to implement a custom tag which something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:custom="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/custom"
            template="/WEB-INF/layouts/layout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="centerColumn">
        <custom:secured roles="ROLE_ABC"/>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

This value should be passed to a filter (before/during the page load) so that I can check whether the authenticated user has the required role or not. If not, I will re-direct him to unauthorized.xhtml page.

Is it possible if yes, sample pseudo-code will be much appreciated.

Comment: I see no reason not to use the normal way to get the security roles. Check this link:http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.de/p/jee-6-security.html

Comment: There will be a custom role based access control model (user,role,permission, etc.). Therefore I need a custom tag which feeds a filter.

Comment: And implement a REST interface and persist this role in database is not possible? Check user roles in database is not rocket science

Comment: Yes I know. Let's skip the custom RBAC model. I want to implement a custom JSF component and access the assigned value from a filter and based on the value I want to redirect the request. Is it possible, do you have a solution for this part?

Comment: I just know how to pass parameter based on mkyongs posting https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-pass-parameters-to-jsf-2-0-template-file/